# Which Youtube API do I use to search for videos?

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, jsonp

I want a client-side API.  In Javascript, I want to input a string of text, and then have the YouTube API give me a JSON Object for the videos.

Which API does that? Can someone give me example code that does this?